# Create VB6 application using a class in a DLL,  then swap out that DLL after build?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, com-interop

so my question is relatively simple, can I create VB6 application that references a class in a dll, and then substitute that dll for another at runtime?

Now my intial guess is... no chance in VB6.

So my thoughts turned to a VB.net interop dll. Could I do it in here, and then call the interop dll from the VB?

Again, my guess would be no.... but I'd be happy if someone knew differently.

The only thing that I think would actually work would be DI in .Net, but I'm limited to .net 2, or 3.5 at a big push, so I dont know if that is possible.

**So for the background....**

I have a dll that a specific site uses, but we dont want to ship that out to everyone. Instead, we want to build a clone dll which just has the interfaces setup so that the VB6 build will complete.
When it gets to the site that needs it, they want to replace the dummy dll, and drop in their version instead.

Note: We do use RegFreeCOM when its gets installed, so I do have the manifest files that I could play around with if needed.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Nick

Comment: Could you use late-binding in VB6 instead of a hard reference to the dll?

Comment: You can test this in about 10 min. Create a dll project, put one class with one method that returns a string, code it to return "abc". write a test harness, add a reference, call the method and show it. Now write another dll in a new project. Same class name, same method name, return "def". Copy the dll over the first one in the test harness folder and run the test harness. I think you'll see the new string, but testing is believing. I would do it if I had VB6 on this machine, probably quicker than typing the comment.

Comment: This is one of the fundamental reasons of having code in a DLL instead of in the application (code re-use/sharing is another)

Comment: Thanks Kate. Managed to get it tested and it does as you say it would. I was expecteing DLL Hell, and am pleasantly supprised.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its a COM dll so its not statically linked to the VB6 exe, so long as the clsids and interface ids are the same in the type library for both DLLs, you can swap them around as you see fit. (If its a VB6 dll this is trivial to do with the 'binary compatibility' build option)

Comment: Thanks Alex. One of my quandries was how to force teh CLSID and TLBID to be identical, and the binary compatability did that for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use late binding instead and instead of making a reference directly in your VB6 code, you would create an object and then set that object to an instance.
Examples and information:

[MVPS](http://word.mvps.org/fAQs/InterDev/EarlyvsLateBinding.htm)

[Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245115)

Comment: This is really not necessary, because the premise of the question was incorrect. He assumed swapping in a new DLL was not possible when in fact it is.

Comment: @DaveInCaz The reason I suggested this was there was nothing in the question guaranteeing binary compatibility was possible. You, and the accepted answer, are both correct in that if the DLLs are binary compatible, you do not need to late bind. If the DLLs were not for some reason, then late binding would be the better option.