# Calling a function using C# Interop library without class defined

Tags: c#, vb6

I have a VB6 application that i need to be able to switch a reference from one dll to another (that i am writing)

It needs to be able to call someFunction() without adding in a class

Such as

in vb6:

```vb
Dim test As SomeObject
Set SomeObject = someFunction("test")
```

These two dlls need to be interchangable code wise.  We only want one reference to change in the resulting program to do two different things

It seems that C# does not allow interop (because of COM restrictions) of static functions; though i still need a function exposed to vb6 that fulfills this requirement

Comment: So, you're saying C# doesn't allow what you need..?

Comment: more specifically the COM standard doesn't allow me to do what i need.  And I'm wondering if anyone knows a good solution to this as standard lib has been doing this kind of stuff for ages

Comment: Was "standard lib" implemented in VB6? AFAICR there was a special feature that allowed you to create special classes in a VB6 COM DLL, and the methods of that class would appear to be static functions to a VB6 client. Behind the scenes I think the runtime created an instance of the class to enable this to happen. I can't now remember the name of the feature. "global singleuse" or "global multiuse" or something? I can't remember whether you can emulate this in a C# interop library. If I have time later I will try to dig it out the answer from my books...

Comment: @MarkJ 
If you can find anything about it I'd love to hear it.  I've been banging my head against this wall for a day or so now and I've tried so many different things.  I know COM objects require instantiation but i was hoping that maybe it could be done DLL side on loading it or something like that (like an Init function) but calling it would still have the same issue of adding the instantiated object

Comment: @MarkJ (apologies for double reply; ran out of room) I'm not sure if standard lib was implemented, but i thought you could still call it.  I'm running VB6 with the last service pack, so I'm using the latest functionality.   I just don't use VB6 too much outside of work related stuff so i don't know too much about it

Comment: I don't understand why your 2 DLLs can't just have identically-named classes, with identically-named functions, that operate differently. Why do you need to avoid a class reference?

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs that's the issue; the original dll has static functions that have no class associated.  So i can't just swap them out which is frustrating.  I did find that C++ allows for this behavior but that means i need two DLL refs instead of swapping one (which is fine but not preferred)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer; I just wasn't looking in the right place for a while.

[UnmanagedExports (Repacked)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports.Repack/)

A very useful nuget package that exports functions with the attribute "DllExport"

For example:

In C#

```
[DllExport]
public static void HelloWorld() { return "Hi!" }
```

Can be called from the VB6 application like so

```
Private Declare Function HelloWorld Lib "MyCSharpDll.dll" () As String
```

And sometime later in the code simply call it (this is if you wanted to output to like a MsgBox persay)

```
MsgBox HelloWorld()
```

Which will simply return "Hi!" in a message box

isn't that kind of cool?

You can view the exports from your .dll with this command from the Developer Console

```
dumpbin /EXPORTS MyCSharpDll.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the code why not adding a new module and add that function. In the body  of the function call to the COM  object as usual. In this way you don't have to change all the references to the function call in your code, what I think is  you want to avoid.

Comment: I want to avoid it if i can but that's not a bad solution
the reason being I want to be able to (in some specific cases) replace the dll without recompiling as some of our users have really.... weird (mostly really old) installations that have a lot of outdated refs that i don't want to fight with when installing.  In those cases if i can just copy and replace the dll I would be happy

Comment: @SLWW Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170297/create-vb6-application-using-a-class-in-a-dll-then-swap-out-that-dll-after-bui) would be useful?  Seems to be the idea you are looking to implement.

Comment: Thanks @BrianMStafford, that should help me once i get through most of the hurtles of this annoying (and unnecessary) restraint put on me by the COM standard :/